# How to sum values of two unequal vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have two unequal vectors in length.
For example,
I want to add all values from `TT` to all values from `FF`.

```
TT <- c(1:10)
FF <- c(0, 60, 120, 180)
```

I would expect to have the below result

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190
```

I would appreciate if you could give me some advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(TT, FF, FUN = `+`))
```

or with `sapply`

```
c(sapply(TT, `+`, FF))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun. `sapply` fits my aim.